# How to use rst.FindFirst with rst.NoMatch?

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

My code works except for this one line

```
.FindFirst "[DONOR_CONTACT_ID] = strTemp2"
```

I want my code to check if there is a record, where a specific DONOR_CONTACT_ID exists becaue there are multiple records with the same DONOR_CONTACT_ID. If that record does not exist, then I want to add that DONOR_CONTACT_ID and RECIPIENT_CONTACT_ID to RECIPIENT_1. If that record does exist, I want to add the RECIPIENT_CONTACT_ID to RECIPIENT_2 for that specific DONOR_CONTACT_ID. To do this, I used .FindFirst, to see if there was a record, then used .NoMatch. If there isn't a match, I want to add a new record, but if there is then I want to check to see if it has to go in RECIPIENT_2.

The error I get is "does not recognize 'strTemp2' as a valid field name or expression". I want to see if the record is equal to strTemp2, but I think my syntax is wrong. Thanks for any help!!

Here is my code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function UsingTemps()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstOutput As DAO.Recordset
'Defines DAO objects
Dim strTemp1 As String
Dim strTemp2 As String
Dim strVal As String
Dim strRecip As String

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Q_RECIPIENT_SORT")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Q_DELETE_T_OUTPUT")
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Set dbs = CurrentDb

Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("T_RECIPIENT_SORT", dbOpenDynaset)
'rst refers to the table T_RECIPIENT_SORT
Set rstOutput = dbs.OpenRecordset("T_OUTPUT", dbOpenDynaset)
'rstOutput refers to the table T_OUTPUT

rst.MoveFirst
'first record
strTemp1 = rst!DONOR_CONTACT_ID
'sets strTemp1 to the first record of the DONOR_CONTACT_ID
rst.MoveNext
'moves to the next record


    Do While Not rst.EOF
    'Loop while it's not the end of the file
        strTemp2 = rst!DONOR_CONTACT_ID
        'strTemp2 = DONOR_CONTACT_ID from T_RECIPIENT_SORT

    If strTemp1 = strTemp2 Then
    'Runs if temps have same DONOR_CONTACT ID
        strRecip = rst!RECIPIENT_CONTACT_ID
    'Sets strRecip = RECIPIENT_CONTACT_ID FROM T_RECIPIENT_SORT

        With rstOutput
        'Uses T_OUTPUT table
            If .RecordCount > 0 Then
            'If table has records then you can check
                .FindFirst "[DONOR_CONTACT_ID] = strTemp2"
                If .NoMatch Then
                    .AddNew
                    !DONOR_CONTACT_ID = strTemp1
                    !RECIPIENT_1 = strRecip
                    .Update
                Else

                    If !DONOR_CONTACT_ID = strTemp2 Then
                        If IsNull(!RECIPIENT_2) And Not (IsNull(!RECIPIENT_1)) Then
                            .Edit
                            !RECIPIENT_2 = strRecip
                            .Update
                        End If
                        .AddNew
                        !DONOR_CONTACT_ID = strTemp2
                        !RECIPIENT_1 = strRecip
                        .Update
                    End If
                End If

            Else
                .AddNew
                !DONOR_CONTACT_ID = strTemp2
                !RECIPIENT_1 = strRecip
                .Update
            End If

        End With

    End If

    strTemp1 = strTemp2
    rst.MoveNext

Loop

Set dbs = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Build the *value* of the variable, instead of the variable *name*, into the string you give `FindFirst` to find.

Assuming `DONOR_CONTACT_ID` is text data type, also include quotes around the variable's value ...

```vb
.FindFirst "[DONOR_CONTACT_ID] = '" & strTemp2 & "'"
```

But if it's numeric, you don't need those quotes ...

```vb
.FindFirst "[DONOR_CONTACT_ID] = " & strTemp2
```

Comment: Second day in a row you have helped me! Thanks again! No one else in my office knows how to code, so I really appreciate that you've helped me the past two days and saved me so much time!