# Setting User Permissions Within MS Access on Login

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am currently working within MS Access 2016. One of the requirements for the project that I am working on is tying the users Windows login to MS Access. I am only grabbing the users "User Name". Within Access there will be permissions set to users within a table. Once the users login based upon there permissions they will be directed to their specific opening page. I was able to successfully retrieve the users windows login but I am having trouble connecting to my back end table.

My Table name is tblUser the field names are:

```
FName LName postion UserName(PK) EmployeeType_ID
```

The code that I have is below I am getting a Run-time error '3077' "Syntax error in string in expression" at "rs.FindFirst "UserName='". I am not sure what the problem is any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Debug.Print Environ("UserName")
Debug.Print Environ$("ComputerName")

Dim strVar As String
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 255
    strVar = Environ$(i)
    If LenB(strVar) = 0& Then Exit For
    Debug.Print strVar
Next

Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblUser", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

rs.FindFirst "UserName='"

If rs.NoMatch = True Then
    MsgBox "You do not have access to this database.", vbInformation, "Access"
    Exit Sub
End If

If rs!EmployeeType_ID = 4 Then

    Dim prop As Property
    On Error GoTo SetProperty
    Set prop = CurrentDb.CreateProperty("AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, False)

    CurrentDb.Properties.Append prop

SetProperty:
    If MsgBox("Would you like to turn on the bypass key?", vbYesNo, "Allow Bypass") = vbYes Then
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = True
    Else
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = False
    End If

End If

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmManager"
DoCmd.Close acForm

If rs!EmployeeType_ID = 3 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmGeneral_User"
    DoCmd.Close acForm
End If

If rs!EmployeeType_ID = 2 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAdmin"
    DoCmd.Close acForm
End If

If rs!EmployeeType_ID = 1 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmGuest"
    DoCmd.Close acForm
End If

End Sub
```

p.s. I fully understand that someone can bypass the security controls set within Access. This is specifically for functionality.

Comment: looks like this question is not related to AD, you should check .FindFirst syntax - there is unclosed string. See correct example in answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616069/how-to-use-rst-findfirst-with-rst-nomatch

Comment: Thank you @sarh I have changed the title for my question. I am currently looking into the other post.

Comment: @sarh Thank you the example within the post fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below part of what I use when grabbing data from a backend:

You can modify the below to pull that specific individuals access rights, you can then set the correct userform to be displayed based on the data pulled from the back end.

```
 Dim acc As Access.Application
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim strPassword As String
 Dim DBpath As String
 Dim DBname As String
 Dim tblStructure As String

 DBpath = "C:\Projects 
 DBname = "Self Serve Database.accdb"
 tblStructure = "_tbl_Structure"
 strPassword = "OpenSesame"

 strSQL = "INSERT INTO _tbl_Structure " & _
          "SELECT * " & _
          "FROM [MS Access;pwd=" & strPassword & ";database=" & DBpath & "\" & DBname & "].[" & tblStructure & "] " & _
          "WHERE [USER ID] = '" & Environ("username") & "'"
```